# The image cannot update other components (MVC)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
```

I have several other frames (two are just punching numbers in, and another is also a scrollbar). I can use other components to update this view (this basically displays a box of image based on the temperature scale). Similarly, I can update other components from this view.

***However*** (edited), the bar does move, but the image stays the same....
Can anyone see a bug? I appreciate any inputs into this/ Thank you!

Comment: A bug in your *imports?* No.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're replacing the label, you need to `remove()` the component and `validate()` the `Container`. Alternatively, just replace the icon.

Addendum: I think the latter approach is preferable. Lacking your images and remaining code, let's start from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170233): initialize the label and slider:

```
final JLabel label = new JLabel(pig);
final JSlider slider = new JSlider();
```

Then in the listener, use `setIcon()`:

```
@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    if (slider.getValue() < 50) {
        label.setIcon(pig);
    } else {
        label.setIcon(dog);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi. how would i go about replacing the icon? do you mean       imagePanel.remove(imageLabel);
      imagePanel.revalidate(); and with the rest of the add?

Comment: I was working up a full example, but this _is_ homework:-) I started [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170233) and used `label.setIcon` in the slider's listener.