# Java Swingworker Thread

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a question to ask about Java Concurrency. I'm practicing Java Threading. What i do is create a simple interface which has a button and a JSlider. So when i click the button a variable will increase and the JSlider moving accordingly. Now I wonder if  Swingworker is a right  choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to use SwingWorker for long-running tasks. What you describe will be performed instantly. Therefore you can do this on the Event Dispatch Thread, where all ActionListeners are performed.

Comment: I dont think so ... because the variable need to attach to the thread and increase gradually and the JSlider moving according to the variable value. If i used just the while loop to do this. The interface will be freezed

Comment: Then, yes, you can use SwingWorker. But there is also javax.swing.Timer, which is made for what you seem to be describing in the comment.

Comment: Do i have to call repaint() on the JSlider. Thanks

Comment: Please just, one question per page - but no, you don't need to call repaint.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2065760/230513) your code first.

- Examples where a state change does *not* block the EDT: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10208380/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522387/230513).
- An example where an action *might* block the EDT: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530659/230513).
- An example where an action *will* block the EDT: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513).