# How do I Highlight buttons when mouse pointer is hovered upon them in Java(Like Start button highlights in XP)?

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, jbutton

If mouse pointer is hovered on start button in Windows XP, it highlights.  I want to do the same in Java.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Java is to JavaScript what car is to carpet. so please confirm whether its a java app or javascript on a web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is to create an Icon for your button to be displayed on rollover and then add it to the button via its setRolloverIcon.  The mouse's model will do all that is needed to display this Icon.

And even another solution is to add a ChangeListener to the button's model.  In the listener if isRollover() returns true, change the display.

E.G. of 1st technique.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

class ButtonRollover {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL imageUrl2 = new URL("http://pscode.org/media/stromlo2.jpg");
        URL imageUrl1 = new URL("http://pscode.org/media/stromlo1.jpg");

        final Image image2 = ImageIO.read(imageUrl2);
        final Image image1 = ImageIO.read(imageUrl1);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JButton button = new JButton("Hover Me!");

                button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image2));
                button.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(image1));

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, button);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Note:  You might also use a `MouseListener`, but since this is a much better answer, I deleted my answer to that effect.

Comment: @Andrew: but I liked it, especially the Halal part.  Nice SSCCE, by the way.

Comment: Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170134/java-swing-jcomponent-size/4170233#4170233).

Answer (score 1):

Is this for a web page? If so, you can easily do this sort of thing with CSS.

Further information is required, really.

Comment: No, not for web page.. Just for simple java application