# Jython Swing: Randomly Occurring Java ImageIO IOException

Tags: java, python, swing, jython

I've built a Jython swing app using eclipse and pydev. I've used simple images for the backgrounds of all of the buttons. 95% of the time, everything works wonderfully. However, about 5% of the time when adding or removing content from the screen, this occurs:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"  at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1310)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1579)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1438)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1342)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)

javax.imageio.IIOException: javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data
```

The frustrating thing is that it's not readily reproducable, and can happen anywhere in the application that I draw a PNG. I can certainly catch the exception and have it reimport the image, but I'm hoping to figure out the root cause.

I call the resources like so:

```
notPressed = ImageIO.read(pkg_resources.resource_stream('images', "button-blue.png")).getScaledInstance(width,height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )
```

My only guess is that sometimes pkg_resources might fail to open a filestream, causing the exception. Any suggestions on how to track this down, or should I just be happy that I can make it fail quietly?

Comment: Are you calling `ImageIO.read()` on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)?

Comment: Exactly -- this intermittent NPE smells very suspicious for a concurrency problem. I think that it's fine to call ImageIO.read() on a background thread as long as you don't  use the images until they are complete and as long as all Swing calls (such as adding an ImageIcon to a JLabel) are done on the EDT.

Comment: I am. Assuming that's the issue, what's more practical solution; having a thread cache all of the images somewhere accessible on application start-up or sending a thread for each individual image. I use roughly 2-3 MBs of images throughout the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's a more practical solution: having a thread cache all of the images somewhere accessible on application start-up or sending a thread for each individual image. I use roughly 2-3 MBs of images throughout the application.

Much depends on the anticipated latency and image size. This simple [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/googleolympiad) caches images as acuired in a `List<ImageIcon>`; the slight delay for a new image is imperceptible, as the images are part of the distribution JAR. In contrast, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4170233/230513) lags palpably as the application acquires images from the network at startup.

For long latency or a large number of large images, you may want to consider [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), as discussed in this Oracle article on how to [*Improve Application Performance With SwingWorker*](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/swingworker/).

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to cache everything, probably as a Jython dictionary of imageicons. The images are already distributed along with the application. I just hadn't seen the need to load them off of the UI thread until now.