# Set Image Icon in Panel

Tags: java, swing

I want to set an image icon in a panel.I am trying to do like this ;

```
 JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("logo.jpg"))
 panelHeader.add(label);
 add(panelHeader);
```

But the image is not showing.Any suggestion what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that show the layout of the container to which you add the label.

Comment: Which IDE you are using, or you doing it manually. You got wonderful answers, this thread regarding, [How to Access Images (Application Resouces)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), might can help you further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `new ImageIcon()` constructor just creates an uninitialized image icon. You must invoke the [`createImageIcon()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) method that returns `ImageIcon` source to assign to your also created `ImageIcon` object.

```
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("logo.jpg", "my logo");
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
```

Comment: what should i import for createImageIcon method?

Comment: Obviously it returns ImageIcon object. ImageIcon class belongs to swing that belongs to the javax.

Answer (score 3):

```
new ImageIcon("logo.jpg")
```

The `String` based constructor for an `ImageIcon` presumes the string represents a file path.  Since this is an image that is added to a panel, by run-time, it will likely be inside a Jar and not accessible as a `File`.  For an embedded application resource, the only viable access is by `URL`.  The URL might be obtained from something like:

```
URL logoUrl = this.getClass().getResource("/logo.jpg");
```

Note the leading `/`.  That tells the JRE to search for the resource on a path relative to the root of the class-path, as opposed to a path relative to the package of the class that loads it.

Answer (score 3):

You've got two good answers on creating the `ImageIcon`. You should also look at the layout of the container to which you add the label. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4170233/230513) uses `FlowLayout`, the implicit default for `JPanel`.

Comment: I'm still waiting to see that SSCCE, in order to determine if the layouts are also affecting the non-appearance of the image.  +1 for both ideas.

Comment: The odds are with you; but I have examined the entrails, and I'm going to stand/sit pat. :-)

Comment: Well, haruspication has never let me down before, so my answer might be wrong. Be careful where you sit, those entrails get everywhere.  :)